# Integrate XBRLware to Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am at the absolutely basic level on Python 3 (everything i currently know is from [TheMonkeyLords](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8830E081324343F1)) and my main focus is to integrate Python 3 with XBRLware so that i can extract financial information from the SEC EDGAR database with accuracy and reliability.

How can i use the [xbrlware frame](https://code.google.com/p/xbrlware/) with Python 3? I have absolutely no idea how you can use a frame with Python 3....

Any suggestions on what should I learn or code for me to study, clues etc would be great help!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it. Based on personal experience, it is very difficult to extract useful financial data from XBRL. XBRLWare does work, but there is a lot of work to do afterwards to extract the data into something useful.

XBRL has over 100 definitions of "revenue". Each industry reports differently. Each company makes 100s of filings and you have to string together data from different reports. It's an incredibly frustrating process.

I have used XBRLWare as a Ruby Gem on Windows. (It is no longer supported.) It does "work". It downloads and formats the reports nicely, but it operates as a viewer. Most filings contain two quarters of data. (Probably not the quarters you want either.)

You can use the XBRL viewer on the SEC's website to accomplish the same thing. Or you can go to the company's 10-Qs.

Also, XBRL uses CIK codes for the companies. As far as I know, the SEC doesn't have a central database to match CIK codes to ticker symbols (if you can believe that!). So it can be frustrating to find the companies you want to download.

If you want to download all the XBRL filings, I've been told its like 6TB a month.

You can't pull historical financial data from XBRL either.  You have to string two quarters at a time together. So, pull every IBM filing (XBRL is 3 yrs old) and string together all the 10-Qs. XBRL is only three years old for the large accelerated filers, so historical data is limited.

There is a reason why Wall Street still charges $25k/year for financial data. XBRL is very difficult to use and difficult to extract data from.

You could try: XBRLcloud.com or findynamics.com

Comment: What about Arelle (http://arelle.org/). I can download with arelle the data and then just put them inside an Excel file. It seems quite stable